# dyld: Symbol not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, framework

Начал писать под мак новое приложение и почти сразу получил ошибку

[image]

Насколько я понял проблема с frameworks,  однако переподключил фреймворки и ничего не помогло.

[image]

Как избавиться от этой проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

Получилось исправить. Как я понял эта проблема была связана каким-то образом с обновлениями X-Code. Обновил до 7.2 все заработало